# How should I open an Excel Workbook from MS Word VBA

Tags: excel, vba, macos, ms-word

There are other variants of this question on StackOverflow, but they're all from several years ago and the answers from them seem to reference older versions of VBA...  or at least they give me errors I've been unable to resolve otherwise. Here's my code, written through the MS Visual Basic Editor, Version 7.1, running on Mac OS Mojave 10.14.5. Word & Excel are both version 16.26. Each Sub below is a different attempt. I'm new to VBA, so trying lots of things that I don't quite understand.  Each Sub gives a different error:

```
Sub OpenExcelFile1()
    Dim oExcel As Excel.Application
    Dim oWB As Excel.Workbook
    Dim granted as Boolean
    Debug.Print "a"

    Set oExcel = New Excel.Application
    granted = GrantAccessToMultipleFiles(Array("/users/sarah/workspace/report-writer/"))
    Debug.Print "b"
    Set oWB = oExcel.Workbooks.Open("/Users/sarah/workspace/report-writer/test.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True)
    Debug.Print "c"
End Sub
```

OpenExcelFile1 above hangs for about a minute between "a" and "b", then gives `Run-time error '-2146959355 (80080005)': Automation error`

```
Sub OpenExcelFile2()
    Dim oWB As Excel.Workbook
    Dim granted As Boolean
    granted = GrantAccessToMultipleFiles(Array("/Users/sarah/workspace/report-writer/"))
    Debug.Print "d"

    Set oWB = Excel.Workbooks.Open("/Users/sarah/workspace/report-writer/test.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True)
    Debug.Print "e"
End Sub
```

OpenExcelFile2 above gets to "d", then gives `Run-time error '430': Class does not support Automation or does not support expected interface.`

```
Sub OpenExcelFile3()
    Dim oWB As Excel.Workbook
    Dim granted As Boolean
    granted = GrantAccessToMultipleFiles(Array("/Users/sarah/workspace/report-writer/"))
    Debug.Print "f"

    Set oWB = Excel.Application.Workbooks.Open("/Users/sarah/workspace/report-writer/test.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True)
    Debug.Print "g"
End Sub
```

OpenExcelFile3 gets to "f", then prints the same error as OpenExcelFile2

```
Sub OpenExcelFile4()
    Dim oWB As Excel.Workbook
    Dim granted As Boolean
    granted = GrantAccessToMultipleFiles(Array("/Users/sarah/workspace/report-writer/"))
    Debug.Print "h"
    Set oWB = Excel.Application.WorkbookOpen("/Users/sarah/workspace/report-writer/test.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True)
    Debug.Print "i"
End Sub
```

OpenExcelFile4 gets to "h", then prints the same error as OpenExcelFile2 and OpenExcelFile3.

The referenced test.xlsx exists at the specified location, with 777 permissions.

I have installed (checked? used? referenced?) the following six references:
 * Visual Basic For Applications
 * Microsoft Word 16.0 Object Library
 * Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library
 * Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library
 * Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library
 * Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3

What am I missing?
Thank you.

Comment: Which version of Office? FWIW there appear to be major problems with "automation" between Office applications on more recent versions for the Mac. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52623911

Comment: Word and Excel are both version 16.26; I assume that's the Office version too. I saw some notes about rolling back to earlier versions of Office, and bugs in one of the recent versions, but everything I saw was from over a year ago...  Surely MS patches their major bugs more often than that.... right? please?

Comment: Some things get fixed, others not...

Comment: ***LOL*** "Surely MS patches their major bugs more often than that.... right? please?"

Comment: FWIW, I've also tried analogous code in Excel VBA to open Word docs.  The errors are different, but the end result (failure) is the same: SNAFU.

Comment: Here's a link telling how to roll back, and hinting version 16 isn't fully compatible with version 15 and earlier standards: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/how-to-go-back-to-office-2016-for-mac-15-xx-versions-from-16-xx-e88ed6c8-6fb4-40a1-9540-529000d3d20f

Comment: Tried downgrading Excel & Word to v 15. Still getting errors & crashes on every option I've described in both the Word -> Excel and Excel -> Word scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Found *a* solution which I dislike:

1. Use Windows, not Mac.
2. Remove the `GrantAccessToMultipleFiles` lines, since this function is only present in the Mac version of VBA
3. Remove the reference to "Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library" (I can't find it on Windows. It's probably innocuous if it's on someone else's machine.)

Am posting this as a "solution" because with these modifications because they let me do the basic open-excel-file operation for the methods OpenExcelFile1, OpenExcelFile2, and OpenExcelFile3.  The last one, OpenExcelFile4 did not work. It appears the Application.WorkbookOpen() is not present in Windows either. This was tested and working for Windows 10 Pro v 1903 build 18362.175 with MS VBA version 7.1 and Office version 16.

I don't like the solution because the specific project I'm researching this for is Mac-primary. If others have a Mac-friendly solution, I'd love to see it.

Comment: Application.Workbooks.Open is the correct syntax. There is NO Application.WorkbookOpen method for Excel. The Microsoft Forms 2.0 library should be available on every machine that has Office VBA installed. But if you're not using UserForms it doesn't matter whether the reference is activated or not.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably missing a reference to the DLL that supports the automation of Excel from Word. Try adding the reference by entering the VBA editor, then clicking `Tools > References`  then scrolling down the list to `Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library`. Your version might vary; I'm (apparently) on Office v16.

Comment: I've got checked the Excel 16 Obj Lib, also VB for Apps Extensibility, VB for Apps, Word 16 Obj Lib, Forms 2 Obj Lib, and Office 16 Obj Lib.  Will add the list of references to the question.